# Control of colors of isolines, gnuplot unfortuantely lways starts with first color

Tags: gnuplot

When plotting isolines gnuplot uses the first defined color for the first used iso line, therefore the color depends on the actual values and not on the definition of the iso line.

I have a sequence over time of 3D plots and want to have the same colors for the same iso line, where not all isolines are used in all plots. Today there is a shift in colors, which makes it not easy to follow the results.

```
eset;set terminal pdfcairo color noenhanced
set output "exa03_W2_d60b_wgV54_sfkin.pdf"
date = system("echo %date% %time%")
set key title date."  "
set hidden3d; set grid
set contour both
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set zrange[ -3.834277 :   3.969362]
set cntrparam level discrete   -3.834277 ,  -3.053914 ,  -2.273550 ,  -1.493186 ,  -0.712822 ,   0.067542 ,   0.847906 ,   1.628270 ,   2.408634 ,   3.188998

...
set title "exa03_W2_d60b_wgV54.00009.sfkin    step     9/  1024   t=  4.50 sec
splot "exa03_W2_d60b_wgV54.00009.sfkin" u 1:2:3 w l title " "
set title "exa03_W2_d60b_wgV54.00010.sfkin    step    10/  1024   t=  5.00 sec
splot "exa03_W2_d60b_wgV54.00010.sfkin" u 1:2:3 w l title " "
...

set output
```

Isolione 0.0675 is drawn blue in step 9, but green in step 10. I would like t o plot it according to the `cntparam level discrete` defintion always with the 6th color.

see results in https://i.stack.imgur.com/SncoG.jpg

Is there a trick to achieve this?

Comment: @ethan I found a suitable workaround to work with palettes (https://imgur.com/a/ixB08u0) 
I have no direct control about the level of the isolines, but the colors are not changing from one to another, which is my main concern.

I am using gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 6a

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is `set cntrparam firstlinetype N`.
In brief, you can define any sequence of fixed line properties that you want and then tell the contouring routines to use that sequence.

```
# Custom contour lines starting at 101
set linetype 101 lc "gray"
set linetype 102 lc "black" lw 0.5 dt '.'
set linetype 103 lc "black" lw 0.5 dt '-'
set linetype 104 lc "black" lw 0.5
set linetype 105 lc 6

set cntrparam firstlinetype 101 sort
```

For examples of use see the online demo [custom_contours.dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.3/custom_contours.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this hasnt solved my issue, see https://imgur.com/a/Z5L3osE . The level `0.292` is printed with different isolines in different plots. My input looks like :

```
set contour both
set zrange[ -2.805356 :   3.390333]
set cntrparam level discrete   -2.805356 ,  -2.185787 ,  -1.566218 ,  -0.946649 ,  -0.327080 ,   0.292489 ,   0.912058 ,   1.531626 ,   2.151196 ,   2.770765
set linetype 101 lc "gray" 
...set linetype 105 lc 6
set cntrparam firstlinetype 101 sort
set title "exa02_W5_wsp0_3D_wgV54.00008.sfkin    step     8/   128   t=  4.00 sec
```